# Mega menu - slide panels in direction based on clicked link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a "mega menu" which has large panels that slide in and out below the navigation. The problem I am facing is getting the panels to slide in the direction based on if the clicked link is before or after the currently visible link(so if you click a link that comes after the currently visible link, the current panel should slide off the screen to the left and the new panel should slide in from the right). If you click the links in order, it works as desired, but when you start clicking the links out of order, the slide direction gets messed up.

```js
$('.navigation a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var prevPanel = $('.navigation a.active').attr('data-panel');
  var currPanel = $(this).attr('data-panel');
  $('.panel').removeClass('active');
  if (currPanel > prevPanel) {
    $('.panel.panel-' + prevPanel).removeClass('active').css('left', '-100%');
    $('.panel.panel-' + currPanel).addClass('active').css('left','0');
  } else {
    $('.panel.panel-' + prevPanel).removeClass('active').css('left', '100%');
    $('.panel.panel-' + currPanel).addClass('active').css('left','0');
  }
  $('.navigation a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body,html {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.navigation {
  text-align:center;
}
.panel {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
  .panel.active {
    left:0;
  }
  .panel-1 {
    background:red;
  }
  .panel-2 {
    background:green;
  }
  .panel-3 {
    background:blue;
  }
  .panel-4 {
    background:orange;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="#" data-panel="1" class="active">Panel 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-panel="2">Panel 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-panel="3">Panel 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-panel="4">Panel 4</a>
</div>
<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel panel-1 active">Panel 1 content</div>
  <div class="panel panel-2">Panel 2 content</div>
  <div class="panel panel-3">Panel 3 content</div>
  <div class="panel panel-4">Panel 4 content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you had to do was reset the positioning before performing the slide-in animation.

```js
$('.navigation a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var prevPanel = $('.navigation a.active').attr('data-panel');
  var currPanel = $(this).attr('data-panel');
  
  $('.panel').removeClass('active');
  if (currPanel > prevPanel) {
    $('.panel.panel-' + prevPanel).removeClass('active').css('left', '-100%');
    $('.panel.panel-' + currPanel).addClass('active').css('left','0');
  } else {
    $('.panel.panel-' + prevPanel).removeClass('active').css('left', '100%');
    $('.panel.panel-' + currPanel).addClass('active').css('left','0');
  }
  // reset positioning
  $(".panel:lt("+ (currPanel - 1) +")" ).css('left','-100%');
  $(".panel:gt("+ (currPanel - 1) +")" ).css('left','100%');
  // continue
  $('.navigation a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body,html {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.navigation {
  text-align:center;
}
.panel {
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  left:100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
  .panel.active {
    left:0;
  }
  .panel-1 {
    background:red;
  }
  .panel-2 {
    background:green;
  }
  .panel-3 {
    background:blue;
  }
  .panel-4 {
    background:orange;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="#" data-panel="1" class="active">Panel 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-panel="2">Panel 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-panel="3">Panel 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-panel="4">Panel 4</a>
</div>
<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel panel-1 active">Panel 1 content</div>
  <div class="panel panel-2">Panel 2 content</div>
  <div class="panel panel-3">Panel 3 content</div>
  <div class="panel panel-4">Panel 4 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it is still not performing as desired. In your snippet, click on "Panel 4" and then click on "Panel 3." Panel 3 slides in from the right when it should be sliding in from the left since it comes before Panel 4 in the list.

Comment: Ah, just noticed that, revising.

Comment: Updated with a better reset. Let me know if this is what you wanted or if you need more adjustments.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!! Will award bounty tomorrow.